# Angular2 - Not receiving post param on server

Tags: c#, angular, post

I'm making a project on Angular 2 and I'm starting to implement a download method, but while testing I notice that my server isn't getting the path of the file. I might have done a mistake that I'm not seeing.
This is my code:

**.component.ts**

```
downloadFile(filePath: string): void{
    this.dataImportService.downloadFile(filePath)
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
}
```

**dataImportService.ts**

```
downloadFile(filePath: string): any{
return this.http.post(SERVICE_URL + 'DataImport/downloadFile', filePath)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => {
    return response.json().ReturnStatus.ReturnObject;
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Analyzing the post on Chrome console, the filePath is being sent but when it gets to my server (c# API) it comes as null.

**DataImportController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public void downloadFile(string path)
    {

        try
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(path).Substring(1);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

            HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.AddHeader("Content-Type", Utils.MimeTypesConverter.GetMimeType(extension));
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(path));

            response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
            return;
        }


    }
```

Any advice?
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: pass via query string, `this.http.post(SERVICE_URL + 'DataImport/downloadFile?filePath='+ filePath`

Comment: and change method to get? since http.post need more parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post data you are sending is just a string. Post data should be of key value pairs, then only you can specify which post data item you are referring to in your backend implementation. Usually, the post data item is of JSON type, in your case that can look like

```
{'file_path': "path/to/the/file"}
```

Comment: I almost tried that before, I did {path: filePath} Thank you for the help!